# Javascript won't put array values in CSS syntax

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a slide show using multiple background-images and using the background-position property to animate them. Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="slide_holder" id="slide_holder"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.slide_holder {
    float: left;
    width: 1440px;
    height: 720px;
    background-image: url("images/gc-h-s-01.jpg"), url("images/gc-h-s-02.jpg"), url("images/gc-h-s-03.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-position: 0px, 1440px, 2880px;
    transition: 1s;
}
```

JS:

```
var imageIndex = 1;
var x;

var PosValues = ["0px, 1440px, 2880px", "-1440px, 0px, 1440px", "-2880px, -1440px, 0px"]

startSlides();

function startSlides() {
    x = setInterval(IncAndWrite, 1000);
}

function IncAndWrite() {
    var i;
    document.getElementById("slide_holder").style.backgroundPosition = PosValues[imageIndex];
    imageIndex++;
    if (imageIndex > 2) {imageIndex = 0;}
}
```

The concept is that the background-position values for each background-image change every 1s keeping only one image in the visible frame.
The above mentioned code works just fine, but I do not want to write individual position values for different screen sizes (as my website is responsive). So I wrote the following code:
JS:

```
var imageIndex = 1;
var x;
var UnitRes = 1440;

var PosValues = [
    UnitRes*0 + "px, " + UnitRes*1 + "px, " + UnitRes*2 + "px;",
    UnitRes*(-1) + "px, " + UnitRes*0 + "px, " + UnitRes*1 + "px;",
    UnitRes*(-2) + "px, " + UnitRes*(-1) + "px, " + UnitRes*0 + "px;"]

startSlides();

function startSlides() {
    x = setInterval(IncAndWrite, 1000);
}

function IncAndWrite() {
    var i;
    document.getElementById("slide_holder").style.backgroundPosition = PosValues[imageIndex];
    imageIndex++;
    if (imageIndex > 2) {imageIndex = 0;}
}
```

The basic concept is that you put the width of the container in UnitRes and then the values get calculated. But this does not seem to work. The background-position values don't change at all.

What I thought was causing the problem:
In the second case of js code I'm putting a variable value inside an array which I thought is not being converted to a string type while inputing it in the CSS syntax.

What I tried doing:
I used `typeof` but it is showing the type as `string`
Then I tried using:

```
document.getElementById("slide_holder").style.backgroundPosition = PosValues[imageIndex].valueOf();
```

but still it's not working. I also used `alert(PosValues[imageIndex]);` to check if the values are ok and they are.

Please help me.

Comment: Try to remove `;`. In first example you are passing values without it and it works. I suppose that causes error

Comment: Yeah that was the cause. It's working fine now. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Could you please post it as an answer so that I can mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that in first time you have defined parameters without semicolon `;` and in second example you have placed it what broke the script.